# Spring Boot AJAX

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

Делаю небольшой проект на Spring Boot. Передаю в контроллер дату, сервис считает кол-во дней между ними и отдает  json. Проблема в обработке на фронте. написал скрипт на JS, который, как я понимаю, не срабатывет. Подскажите, в чем может быть причина. Спасибо!
контроллер:

```java
@RestController
public class RestControllerClass {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/myrequest", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Weekend> catchPostMapping(
            @RequestParam(required = false)
            @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
            @PathVariable(value = "startDate")
            LocalDate startDate,

            @RequestParam(required = false)
            @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
            @PathVariable(value = "endDate")
                    LocalDate endDate){

        Weekend weekend = new Weekend();
        WeekendService service = new WeekendService();
         int days = service.countWeekend(startDate, endDate);
         weekend.setDays(days);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(weekend, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Страница со скриптом:

```
<body>
 <form id = "day">
         start date:
             <input type="date" name="startDate">

          finish date:
             <input type="date" name="endDate">

         <input type="submit" onclick = "myFunction()" value="Calculate!">
     </form>

<p id="paragraph"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {

var formData = JSON.stringify($("#day").serializeArray());
                   $.ajax({
                       url : '/api/myrequest',
                       datatype : 'json',
                       type : 'post',
                       contentType : 'application/json',
                       data : formData,

                       success : function(data) {

                                alert(data);
                       }
                   });
 }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: *который, как я понимаю, не срабатывет.* - как вы это понимаете?

Comment: зачем вы пишите @PathVariable на параметрах, которые не участвуют в пути?

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку получаю только строку с адресом, без алерта
http://localhost:8080/?startDate=2019-05-03&endDate=2019-05-20
если убрать событие с кнопки, и добавить method и action на форму, получаю json. C @PathVariable не разобрался в данном случае, согласен

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте alert в начале скрипта, проверить вызов.
После

```
   success: function (data, textStatus) {
```

добавьте

```
},
  error: function (error) {alert('error :' + eval(error));}
        })  ;
```

Посмотреть, что в ошибке.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).